# Adding KeyListener to a JWindow not getting any key events

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jwindow

In Java, I am adding a KeyListener to a JWindow, but it is not getting any key events. If I used the same code but extend a JFrame instead, then everything works fine.

```
public class MyWindow extends JWindow {
    ...
    ...
    private void initComponents() {
        ...
        ...
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("KEY PRESSED: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("KEY RELEASED: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("KEY TYPED: " +  e.getKeyCode());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Anyone know how can I solve this by using a JWindow?

Please note that I am using Linux, so I am not sure if it is something to do with the platform.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use JWindow instead of JFrame? (I'm curious I hope is not because of the adornments )

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding the `Listener` to the *content pane* of your `JWindow` that you can obtain from `window.getContentPane().addKeyListener(..)` to see if it works.

The problem can be that if you have something focused that is inside the `JWindow` but it is not the `JWindow` itself events will be dispatched to inner focused item. You can also try by adding the `KeyListener` to whatever you've got inside that window..

EDIT:
Searching a little bit on [Sun's forum](http://forums.sun.com) it seems that, to force accepting focus on a `JWindow` API you may do is

```
JWindow myWindow = ...
myWindow.setFocusableWindowState(true);
myWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

if it still doesn't work the best solution is to use a `JFrame`:

```
public class WindowTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    // remove menu bar and title bar
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JWindow window = new JWindow(frame); // this works
    window.setBounds(0, 50, 200, 200);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

- http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=489740&forumID=57
- http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=489740&forumID=57

EDIT2: A complex solution may be to get the `ActionMap` with `getActionMap()` and then add an action for all keyboard keystrokes that just bufferizes it, then you can dispatch them whenever you want (after return key for example)

Comment: I already tried adding it using getContentPane(). As for the possibility that something has has the focus, I tried an empty JWindow and the problem is still there. Once I switch to a JFrame or JDialog without any further changes the listener seems to work.

Comment: @Support - multilanguage SO: I was surprised. Your question about extending `JWindow` remains.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JWindow is pretty much broken in Linux.

The workaround is to use JFrame with `setUndecorated(true)`.

[REGRESSION: JWindow stays on top of all other windows](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5070056)

Answer (score -1):

i also had exactly the same problem...,my solution was that in one class of my package i extended JFrame,on which key listener works perfectly,and in the paint method,i used the graphics instance of `window{Graphics g=win.getGraphics();}`...and i painted everything in the window n not on JFrame...before that i already made a call to `gd{graphicsdevice}.setFullScreenWindow(win);`